Php won't run on VS Code with normal solutions
I am a beginner trying to run Php on my VS Code. I have downloaded XAMPP and had the Apache and MySql started. At first it ran however the second I tried to make a new .php file it no longer works on any of my browser.  At what part should I try to look more? Any help would be appreciated.
I tried to manually delete the vs code file to try an create a new launcher(?) I tried copy pasting the file path to the search bar. Nothing seems to work.

At first, PHP runs inside you XAMPP, not inside your VSCode... So you need to go to your htdocs Directory of your XAMPP, then put there a index.php, this PHP will be loaded if you navigate to localhost in your Browser...
So you write PHP Code in VSCode, you run PHP in XAMPP and in your browser by navigating to localhost, you will see what you have coded...

At first, PHP runs inside you XAMPP, not inside your VSCode...
So you need to go to your htdocs Directory of your XAMPP, then put there a index.php, this PHP will be loaded if you navigate to localhost in your Browser...
So you write PHP Code in VSCode, you run PHP in XAMPP and in your browser by navigating to localhost, you will see what you have coded...
